# reading data from arduino ethernet shield using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, arduino, ethernet

Good Day :D
Im having trouble in reading the data coming from arduino using arduino ethernet shield communication . I want to display the data in vb.net program. Any know how to solve my problem or any one can give me syntax or source code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

TcpListenner & Socket is your friend :

You can see on this link an example for get the data : http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20020323.asp